Extracting building rooftop boundaries
I'm using the 3D Buildings Solution in ArcGIS, and think I finally thought up a solution to my issue but hitting a wall.  One of the steps in the 3D Buildings Solution uses polygons to help it divide buildings by different rooftop shapes(part sloped, with a flat section) otherwise I wind up with a ginormous building with a sloped roof that is completely out of place.
I was thinking if I took the DSM of the buildings, and converted it to polygons it would be the answer but I get all of these little holes and tiny polygons.  Using Reclassify I created a new attribute making 20 'slices' through the buildings and grouped them together which I then dissolved trying to filter the minor changes but not really doing it well enough.  I also used the clip tool to eliminate polygon areas that were not in the footprint
Any ideas on reducing the noise around the building edges that is created in this?  or in a previous step.  Generalize and Regularize didn't really work and I'm at a bit of a loss.  I don't mind taking things to QGIS at the moment either.

